# Ubuntu 20.04 loading ALSA source in PulseAudio fails on startup but works after restarting PulseAudio

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I am trying to set my default source to be a virtual dsnoop device (dmic_sv) defined in `~/.asoundrc`, and I have added to `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` the following lines:

```
# Tried placing the line below both before and after `load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0`,
# but it didn't make a difference
load-module module-alsa-source device=dmic_sv

...
set-default-source alsa_input.dmic_sv
```

At boot, PulseAudio can't find dmic_sv so it fails to load it and set it as the default source, but restarting PulseAudio fixes the problem. I suspect that PulseAudio is loading before ALSA, so restarting PulseAudio after ALSA has loaded is why it works, but I haven't found a good way of fixing it (only the hack below which waits for dmic_sv to appear in the output of `arecord -L`, and then restarts PulseAudio).

```
while ! arecord -L | grep dmic_sv > /dev/null
do
    echo "Waiting for dmic_sv..."
    sleep 2
done
killall pulseaudio
```

Any assistance configuring it the proper way so I don't have to use the hack would be much appreciated!